# Angular doesn't include JWTs in POST requests' headers

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, jwt

A snippet of my code sending a GET request to my Node.js API:

```
// Retrieves a particular scheme from the DB.
public getScheme(name: string): Promise<Object> {

  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set('name', name);
  let reqOpts = new RequestOptions();
  reqOpts.params = params;
  reqOpts.headers = this.authService.getTokenHeader();

  return this.http.get(env.apiURL + "getscheme", reqOpts
  ).toPromise().then(res => {
    //...
  });

}
```

This works as expected, and produces the following HTTP header:

```
{ host: 'localhost:8400',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  referer: 'http://localhost:4200/scheme-editor',
  'access-token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTIzNDU2LCJwdyI6InF3ZXJ0eSIsInRzIjoiMTAvMTMvMjAxNywgMTE6MjI6MzggQU0iLCJpYXQiOjE1MDc4ODY1NTgsImV4cCI6MTUwNzk3Mjk1OH0.Cj2vtIiN1bAgKVWZGJqmwiUiKOuJUBXWtAwHU-NhJCQ',
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'if-none-match': 'W/"2e0-sBkIRAD+lnVAHX1r2P+qGvuGu0E"' }
```

The problem is with my POST request:

```
// Inserts a scheme into the DB.
public insertScheme(scheme: Object): Promise<boolean> {

  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set('scheme', JSON.stringify(scheme));
  let reqOpts = new RequestOptions();
  reqOpts.params = params;
  reqOpts.headers = this.authService.getTokenHeader();

  return this.http.post(env.apiURL + "insertscheme", reqOpts
  ).toPromise().then(res => {
    //...
  });

}
```

It doesn't have the token in its header:

```
{ host: 'localhost:8400',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  referer: 'http://localhost:4200/scheme-editor',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-length': '447',
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

Why does the JWT information disappear from the POST request's header?

Some more info:

The getTokenHeader method:

```
public getTokenHeader(): Headers {
  if (localStorage.getItem(this.token_name) == null) { return null; }
  let header = new Headers();
  header.append(this.token_name, localStorage.getItem(this.token_name));
  return header;
}
```

The token saved in the browser's local storage was made with [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)'s sign function server-side like:

```
var token = jwt.sign({ user.id, user.pass }, "secret", { expiresIn: "1d" });
```

Comment: What does your Auth Service getTokenHeader() method look like (as well as any other related methods)

Comment: @Z.Bagley I included them in the question. URLSearchParams, RequestOptions and Headers are Angular classes.

Comment: The most likely problem is you're sending the request before the headers are received and applied inside the AuthService. `console.log(header)` inside your `getTokenHeader()` method might be useful information.

Comment: In insertScheme() after `reqOpts.headers = this.authService.getTokenHeader();` I put a `console.log(reqOpts.headers);` and the token is there. Does this disprove your guess? Or what do you mean?

Comment: It does disprove it. All I can think is that you're using headers.append then doing a direct assign using `=`. Perhaps using the `.merge()` method on the request option will fix it?

Comment: I finally found what I was doing wrong and posted my answer. Thank you for your help btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was causing the problem.

I just realized that **Angular's Http.[post()](https://angular.io/api/http/Http#post) method has a different parameter list than [get()](https://angular.io/api/http/Http#get) has.**

It has an additional `body` parameter on the second place, and I was feeding the token to that one instead of putting it into `options`, which is the third parameter for the post method.